# Are there any existing laws comparable to Quebec's Bill 20?

Tags: democracy, parties, liberalism, civil-rights, canada

Here is a link that explains more in detail what the bill 20 consists of: http://globalnews.ca/news/1728556/opinion-bill-20-will-turn-every-patient-in-quebec-into-a-number-instead-of-a-person/

Briefly, though, this bill will establish a quota of patients/hours of work in hospitals/days worked per year.

If you consider it, it doesn't seem that bad, but the doctors are trying to victimize themselves, by using the patients as argument or other arguments against this bill(as if the patients will be transformed in numbers, and so on).

I would like to see if there are any similar laws, in other countries or provinces.  Are there quotas? And if so, what are they?  In general the article is written more from a humanistic style than a documented one (with data and charts).

Comment: It seems the article covers the pros and cons fairly well.

Comment: The article is written by one journalist, while I am interested in the opinion of people that are in the skin of patients and-or doctors.

Comment: @VictorBarbarosh - It's actually written by one doctor: `A large proportion of GPs today are women with young families. I am one of them.` and `Tara McCarty, BSc, MD CM, CCFP`

Comment: @Bobson - ok, but stil there is no reference in the article on what is the quota in other provinces, and in general the article is more of a humanistic type than documented one(with data and charts,...); Also, my whole point is missed here - I don't care about the article, I would like someone to provide statistical data which will agree with Barrette's bill 20 or not. I used the article only to give people an idea about what the bill is and have no intention to put it in discussion, at least not in this thread.